# Custom Blog Post Listing in Genesis Sample Child Theme

Tags: wordpress

I want to add several images and divs and also customize the look of my Blog post listing... But i can't find the way to do it.

Here's the Blog Template code

```
<?php
/*
 WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit
 this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications
 in the form of a child theme.
 */

/**
 * Template Name: Blog
 * This file handles blog post listings within a page.
 *
 * This file is a core Genesis file and should not be edited.
 *
 * The blog page loop logic is located in lib/structure/loops.php
 *
 * @category Genesis
 * @package  Templates
 * @author   StudioPress
 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GPL v2.0 (or later)
 * @link     http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis
 */
genesis();
```

and just above the `genesis();` code.. i tried to put some divs and images there.. But i guess that's not the way it works. ..

I also tried to make my own Blog listing template using a normal wordpress code theme..

```
<?php /* 
Template Name: List Post Pages
*/ 
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="content" class="hfeed">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="postmetadata">
      <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
      Posted in
      <?php the_category(', ') ?>
      |
      <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else : ?>
  <h2>Not Found</h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But no luck, what's the right way to do this?

***Update -code below is the one i want.. but instead of having the Content of the page. I want the list of Post with excerpts ....How can i do that????

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Page Template
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
  <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
  <div id="content" class="hfeed">
    <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
    <?php genesis_loop(); ?>
    <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- end #content -->
  <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>
</div>
<!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Im shocked that no one answered my question.. anyway, if someone bumps onto this post with similar problem. The answer is adding

```
<?php query_posts( $args );  ?>
```

just above the `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

All in all, my code looks like this ...

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Page Template
*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div class="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
  <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
  <div id="content" class="hfeed">
    <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
    <?php query_posts( $args );  ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></h2>
      <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="postmetadata">
        <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
        Posted in
        <?php the_category(', ') ?>
        |
        <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- end #content -->
  <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>
</div>
<!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```